# Can a crystal oscillator be used instead of a ceramic filter?

Tags: filter, oscillator

For my FM radio circuit i require a 10.7 MHz ceramic filter. When i asked for it in a shop he gave me a crystal oscillator of 10 MHz value. Can i use the oscillator instead of the filter in my circuit.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Google them, and you should see why a crystal oscillator cannot be substituted for a filter.

Comment: He gave you a "crystal oscillator" or an "oscillator crystal"?

Comment: Just going to throw this out there based on this and your previous question. If you're trying to hodge podge an RF circuit together using whatever components are lying around, the odds of it actually working are nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a crystal, or a crystal filter, but definitely NOT a crystal oscillator.

However note that a crystal filter is likely to have a bandwidth of a couple of kilohertz, and a single crystal may have even less, while a ceramic filter at 10.7 MHz will have a bandwidth about 200 kHz.

So depending on the bandwidth you need, (e.g. you need about 200kHz to receive FM audio) the crystal filter most likely won't do what you want.